# jQuery AJAX 'multipart/form-data' Not Sending Data?

Tags: ajax, jquery, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm at a loss for why I can't get jQuery to pass upload data seeing as the AJAX object appears to be configured correctly, and the correct Content-Type/MIME-Type headers are being sent.

I've tried two separate forms of request--one with a FormData object contained within a literal, and also just passing the FormData object directly.

Unfortunately either way I can't get anything to pass, and both $_FILES and $_POST are empty arrays.

The ideal request I wish to use is as follows:

[image]

Along with the following code:

```
var files = new FormData();

$.each(context.prototype.fileData, function(i, obj) { files.append(i, obj.value.files[0]); });

var request = { action: 'upload', id: response.obj.id, data: files };

$.ajax({

    type        : 'POST',
    url         : context.controller,
    data        : request,
    processData : false,
    contentType : 'multipart/form-data',
    mimeType    : 'multipart/form-data',

    success     : function(r) {
        console.log(r);
        //if (errors != null) { } else context.close();

    },

    error       : function(r) { alert('jQuery Error'); }

});
```

Once again the only response (looking at both the Network tab & Console) when I try to export both $_FILES and $_POST is simply two empty arrays...

Comment: Try changing `contentType` to false

Comment: No luck.  jQuery just changes it to application/xml but still no data in either `$_POST` or `$_FILES`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to pass the `FormData` object as the data parameter

```
var request = new FormData();                   
$.each(context.prototype.fileData, function(i, obj) { request.append(i, obj.value.files[0]); });    
request.append('action', 'upload');
request.append('id', response.obj.id);
$.ajax({

    type        : 'POST',
    url     : context.controller,
    data        : request,
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,                        
    success     : function(r) {
        console.log(r);
        //if (errors != null) { } else context.close();

    },

    error       : function(r) { alert('jQuery Error'); }

});
```

Comment: Interestingly this didn't work at first, but it did once I changed Content-Type to false...

Comment: @Musa @julian how to get context? `context.prototype.fileData` ?