# Node.js/Express Async File Upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've pawed through numerous (and mostly outdated) older stack overflow and Google answers and can't find a damn thing that works with the latest versions of Node and Express.

What is the current go-to plugin for async file uploads?

EDIT: I'm uploading the files to my Node.js server. It's running Express. It should be able to handle any file types.

Comment: Upload to what?  It depends entirely upon what your sending the file to and what kind of uploads it supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) for file uploads. You can either store them inside of a directory or you can use Amazon S3 to store them on their servers. It works like a charm.

Here is what some code looks like:

```
  // At the top of your modules
  var formidable = require('formidable');

  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(); //Receive form

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) { //Parse form and data
     // Do form stuff, you can access the files
  });
```

With jQuery, you can do the following:

```
     $('#your_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url : '/your/url/',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: formData,
            success: function (msg) {
               console.log(msg);
            },
            processData: false
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Is this for async uploads? (ie. the page doesn't refresh) If so, could you show me the front-end html/javascript?

Comment: @opticon, yes. There is a way to do it. jQuery can do that, and I've used it as well.

Comment: @opticon I've updated my code. This should work for you. Good luck.

Comment: So far it's looking good! Care to give me a peak at whats within the form.parse callback function?

Comment: @opticon I recommend you use AWS s3 to store your images. It's what I use. I have the code to do that, however if you're going to store them into your local directories, you'll have to use a built-in module called "filesystem" (var fs = require('fs');) - which one do you want?

Comment: I've used S3 for a few projects in the past, but for this one I'd like to play around locally first. So lets go with that? Would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61380/discussion-between-opticon-and-tiffany-lowe).

Comment: @TiffanyLowe Is there a reason why `contentType` is given twice with different values?

Comment: @AkseliPalén as a matter of fact, I'm sure that's wrong. I've become a much better developer since 2014, so yeah. Pay attention to the first contentType only.

Comment: @TiffanyLowe Thanks. Actually, it is kind of funny, it seems that the `contentType: false` might be the correct one after all, and maybe your code worked back then because of that extra line. If `contentType` is explicitly set to `'multipart/form-data'`, jQuery fails to add correct multipart boundary string to it. That leads to a missing boundary problem on the backend. Sounds odd at first but so it seems to be. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13243501/638546 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/638546.