# How to submit form to an other page using jQuery, Ajax with out leaving my page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, multipartform-data

I want to submit a `multipart/form-data` form without leaving my page or reloading using `jQuery` and `AJAX`. When I submit it with PHP only it does the job well but leaves the page.

HTML:

```
<form  action="" id="myform" method="POST" class="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="image" name="file">
<input  border="4" type="submit" value="submit"  id="sumit" name="submit"  class="button" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $('.myform').submit( function() {
        $.ajax({
             url    : 'c_create.php',
            type    : 'POST',
            data    : formdata(),       
            success : function( data ) {
                         alert('ok');       
                      },
            error   : function(){
                         alert('error');
                      } 
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Either submit your form in an iframe, or send the file via ajax.  This has been covered many times on SO.  Use the search box or google for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use a plugin because the uploading process is quite messy. Especially different browsers have slight differences which makes the code update and maintenance hard. I have tested https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader and it works well.

```js
$(function() {
    var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({

        element : $('#selectImportFile')[0],
        request: {
            // path to server-side upload script
            // url of the server-side upload script, should be on the same 
            endpoint : 'api/docs',
            // additional data to send, name-value pairs
            params : {}
        },
        // validation    
        validation: {
            // ex. ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'] or []
            allowedExtensions : [ 'xlsx', 'docx' ],
            // each file size limit in bytes
            // this option isn't supported in all browsers
            sizeLimit : 0, // max size   
            minSizeLimit : 0, // min size
        },
        // set to true to output server response to console
        debug : true,

        // events
        callbacks: {
            // you can return false to abort submit
            onSubmit : function(id, fileName) {
                qq.log('submit');
            },
            onProgress : function(id, fileName, loaded, total) {
                qq.log('onprogress');
            },
            onComplete : function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                qq.log('completed');
                qq.log('id: ' + id);
                qq.log('fileName: ' + fileName);
                qq.log('responseJSON: ' + responseJSON);
            },
            onCancel : function(id, fileName) {
            },
            onError : function(id, fileName, xhr) {
                qq.log('error');
            }
        },
        showMessage : function(message) {
            qq.log('Server error: ' + message);
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `preventDefault`:

```
$(function(){
   $('.myform').submit( function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      ....
```

or use 'submit button' instead of '.myform':

```
$('#sumit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: shows popup'ok' but does'nt upload the image?

Answer (score 0):

You have to serialize the data of the form,

and also do a preventDefault(), so the submit button doesn't actually do a reload.

```
$(function(){

  $('.myform').submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize(); 
    $.ajax({
         url    : 'c_create.php',
        type    : 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        data    : formData,       
        success : function( data ) {
                     alert('ok');       
                  },
        error   : function(){
                     alert('error');
                  } 
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

Although multi-part forms can be a bit tricky with ajax.

Heres some further help on the matter...

[jQuery AJAX 'multipart/form-data' Not Sending Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831680/jquery-ajax-multipart-form-data-not-sending-data)

Comment: Does'nt work for me, I tried also the link, but with out success.

Answer (score -1):

In other words, `$.ajax();` cannot submit a `multipart/form-data` it's only going to submit the data but not going to submit the file along, you can try using `dojo.form.uploader`.

Comment: I am not allowed to use plusgins. I deside and recomend for any one to use jQuery and ajax for string data and serverside script (php,jsp  etc ) for file upload.

Comment: It'll be more better if you can use a plugin for this issue!