# Image upload with ajax and asp

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

i'm trying to upload images with ajax using the post method but i keep on get error messages. When i do it without ajax with works.

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="" action="<%=editAction%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form2" id="form2">
  <table width="359" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" id="table">
    <tr>
      <td><strong> Name</strong></td>
      <td><label for="name"></label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="115"><strong>Area</strong></td>
      <td width="223"><label for="area"></label>
        <select name="area" id="area">
          <option selected="selected">Public</option>
          <option>Follows</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input name="fileField3" type="file" multiple="multiple" id="fileField3" onchange="dwz_setEvent(this,'change')" onclick="dwz_setEvent(this,'click')" accept="image/*" capture="camera" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input name="fileField2" type="file" multiple="multiple" id="fileField2" onchange="dwz_setEvent(this,'change')" onclick="dwz_setEvent(this,'click')" accept="image/*" capture="camera" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><label for="fileField"></label>
        <input name="fileField" type="file" multiple="multiple" id="fileField" onchange="dwz_setEvent(this,'change')" onclick="dwz_setEvent(this,'click')" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
        <input name="user" type="hidden" id="user" value="1" />
        <input name="time_group" type="hidden" id="time_group" value="2" />
        <input name="ut" type="hidden" id="ut" value="new" />
        <input name="uid" type="hidden" id="uid" value="7" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value=" Upload" class="upload_button" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span style="width: 480px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 30px;"><img src="imgs/page_loader.gif" alt="" name="gif" width="46" id="gif" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 46px; visibility: hidden;" /></span></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

AJAX

```
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form2").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        url: "upload_script.asp",
        data: data,
  success: function(data) {
      $('#msg').html(data);

    var result = $.trim(data);

    if(result==="OK"){
       $.mobile.changePage("#follow");




    }
  }
});
});
});

</script>
```

upload_script.asp

```vb
<%
'*********************************
'*                               *
'*  INSERT RECORD AND UPLOAD     *
'*  http://www.dwzone.it         *
'*                               *
'*********************************
    server.ScriptTimeout = 5400

    Dim RG_altVal, RG_columns, RG_Cong, RG_dbValues, RG_dbValuesTmp, RG_delim, RG_editCmd, RG_editQuery, RG_editQueryTmp, RG_emptyVal, RG_Ext, RG_Extensions, RG_fields, RG_FieldValueTmp, RG_FileDel, RG_FileExt, RG_formVal, RG_FS, RG_i, RG_L, RG_Len, RG_Max, RG_Name, RG_New, RG_newName, RG_Num, RG_Path, RG_Rec, RG_ret, RG_Save, RG_tableValues, RG_tableValuesTmp, RG_tst, RG_typeArray, RG_z, UploadStatus, NumFile
    Dim RG_Connection, RG_editColumn, RG_recordId, Form, editAction, editRedirectUrl, RG_Files, RG_formName, UploadType, ParamVal, ParamList, MaxFieldNumber, TmpVal, x, y, Key, ProgressBar, newFileName
    Dim tmpField_Name(), tmpValue_Name(), tmpField_Size(), tmpValue_Size(), tmpField_Thumb(), tmpValue_Thumb(), QtyRecord, TotalFileSize, valueToRedirectSend

    Set Form = New ASPForm
    Dim UploadID
    UploadID = Form.NewUploadID
    ProgressBar = ""
    TotalFileSize = ""
    editRedirectUrl = "a_upload_msg.asp"
    RG_Connection = MM_viva_web_STRING
    RG_editTable = "dbo.users_pics" 
    RG_Files = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vivaweb\usr_up_img\\;2;;;;1;pic;3;;;;0;;;;;1;fileField3|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vivaweb\usr_up_img\\;2;;;;1;pic;3;;;;0;;;;;1;fileField2|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vivaweb\usr_up_img\\;2;;;;1;pic;3;;;;0;;;;;1;fileField@_@_@2@_@_@0@_@_@0;;;80;0;;;80;0;_small;0;0|0;;;80;0;;;80;0;_small;0;0|0;;;80;0;;;80;0;_small;0;0@_@_@../"
    RG_formName = "form2"
    UploadType="Insert"
    UploadStatus = ""
    valueToRedirectSend = "seen"
    NumFile = 0

    if len(Request.QueryString("UploadID"))>0 then
        Form.UploadID = Request.QueryString("UploadID")
    end if

    if (Request.QueryString <> "") Then
        editAction = CStr(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")) & "?" & Request.QueryString & "&UploadID=" & UploadID
    else
        editAction = CStr(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")) & "?UploadID=" & UploadID 
    End If

Const fsCompletted  = 0

If Form.State = fsCompletted Then 
  if Form.State = 0 then

        Set ParamVal = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        tmp = split(RG_Files,"@_@_@")
        ParamList = split(tmp(0),"|")
        MaxFieldNumber = ubound(ParamList)
        for x=0 to Ubound(ParamList)
            TmpVal = Split(ParamList(x),";")
            for y=0 to ubound(TmpVal)
                Key = right("00" & cstr(x),3) & cstr(y)
                ParamVal.add Key, TmpVal(y)
            next
        next
        Form.Files.Save

        RG_fieldsStr  = "name|value|area|value|user|value|time_group|value|ut|value|uid|value"
        RG_columnsStr = "name|',none,''|area|',none,''|email|',none,''|time_group|',none,''|upload_type|',none,''|up_user_id|none,none,NULL"
        Form.Files.DataBaseInsert

        response.write(getRedirect())
        response.end
  End If
ElseIf Form.State > 10 then
  response.write "<br><Font Color=red>Some form error.<br>Error code: " & Form.State & "<br>Error List:<br>0  Form was successfully processed. <br>1  Request method is NOT post <br>2  Zero length request (there are no data in a source form) <br>3  Form is in a middle of process. <br>5  Initial form state <br>11  Boundary of multipart/form-data is not specified. <br>12  Unknown source form (Content-type must be multipart/form-data) <br>15  Client was disconnected before upload was completted.<br>16  Unexpected error from Request.BinaryRead method (ASP error).<br></Font><br>"
End If


function GetFolderName(str):  GetFolderName = Ris : end function

function myGetFileName(str):  myGetFileName = Ris : end function





%>
```

This is the error message return by the browser

```
Some form error.
Error code: 12
Error List:
0 Form was successfully processed.
1 Request method is NOT post
2 Zero length request (there are no data in a source form)
3 Form is in a middle of process.
5 Initial form state
11 Boundary of multipart/form-data is not specified.
12 Unknown source form (Content-type must be multipart/form-data)
15 Client was disconnected before upload was completted.
16 Unexpected error from Request.BinaryRead method (ASP error).
```

Any help please

Comment: Guessing a lot of this isn't your code...

Comment: It's a It's in I use for the upload which writes the script

Comment: You need to set `contentType: false` in your `$.ajax` properties. See [jQuery AJAX 'multipart/form-data' Not Sending Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12831775/692942) and [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/692942)

Comment: Also `$(this).serialize()` will not work with `multipart/form-data` you will need something to parse the file data and post it as multipart encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use something like http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/ as the $.ajax will not use enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: It doesn't by default but you can tell it to by setting `contentType: false` to stop jQuery destroying the boundary string.