# Classic Asp Persits Upload And Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, vbscript, asp-classic

I have one file input and i want to upload selected file with jquery ajax.

My input like this

```html
<form id="formWithFiles">    
  <input type="file" name="file">
</form>
```

My upload jquery code

```js
$("input[name='file']").on('change',function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'du.asp', 
    type: 'POST',
    contentType:'multipart/form-data',
    data: new FormData($('#formWithFiles')[0]),
    processData: false, 
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

My Upload Classic Asp Code - du.asp

```vb
Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
Upload.CodePage = 65001
Upload.OverwriteFiles = False
Temp = Server.MapPath("content/temp")&"/"
Upload.Save(Temp)
```

Problem is here; I am getting a

> 500 Internal Server Error

error with jquery ajax. But if i use form submit method then file uploading with `du.asp`.

Detailed Error (Just using ajax)

> Boundary not found in Content-Type. Make sure you have included the attribute ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" in your form.

Comment: Suggestions of what?, you haven't stated the problem....does it error, is the error descriptive? First suggestion go here and learn [ask]

Comment: @Lankymart sorry my bad. I edited my question.

Comment: Still not very clear, you may need to enable detailed errors in IIS. See [Detailed 500 error message, ASP + IIS 7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2765795/692942).

Comment: @Lankymart Done I did it! I am answering my question with solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I did it with this code;

```
var formData = new FormData($("#formWithFiles")[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'du.asp',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (returndata) {
            console.log(returndata);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It been [detailed before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12831680/692942) - glad you found the solution.

Comment: Also [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/692942) for another detailed breakdown.